# Assign values to rows from various dataframes within a list, depending on row number

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list `data.rt` of several data.frames, each one with 2 columns and 30 rows. They look something like this

```
   subject response_time
1        1          1323
2        1          1452
3        1          1566
4        1          3444
5        1          9385
...
```

I'd like to add a new column called `part` to all the dataframes within the list, with 2 factors "A" and "B". It should display "A" for the first 15 rows and "B" for the remaining 15 rows. 
The result would be something like this for each dataframe

```
   subject response_time part
1        1          1323    A
2        1          1452    A
3        1          1566    A
... 
15       1          3444    B
16       1          9385    B 
17       1          2886    B
...
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the `list` ('data.rt') using `lapply`, `transform` each of the individual datasets to create the 'part' column with `rep`

```
lapply(data.rt, transform, part = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 15))
```

---

Or using `map` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(data.rt, ~ .x %>%
                   mutate(part = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 15)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had tried to use lapply in some way but coudn't quite get it right

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `dplyr::bind_rows` and merge all data frames together. Perform operation on data. Grouping on `Name` provides flexibility to perform actions specific to individual data frame. Finally, split data frames back to list.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(data.rt, .id = "Name") %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(part = ifelse(row_number() <= 15, "A", "B")) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  split(x = .[-1], f = .$Name)
```

Or other option using `lapply` can be as:

```
lapply(data.rt, function(x){
          x$part <- ifelse(1:nrow(x) <=15, "A", "B") #OR rep(c("A","B"), each = 15)
          x
                   })
```